# install jars to a specified locaiton in maven build

Tags: java, maven, build

I am writing a osgi bundle which needs some third party jars. I have configured user settings file with my central repository so that maven will fetch from jars from central repository. when i am build with goals `clean install` maven inturn place the jars in the local repository. Is there any way to redirect the local repository to another directory so that the bundle will be deployed once maven build process completes

Comment: You can set it in your IDE:

Comment: You mean to say user settings file in eclipse under maven. But i want to change the directory during build process. Is there any way of controlling with flags?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to install your artifacts to a remote repository ?

If so, you'll have to use `maven-deploy-plugin`.